# Import CSV data into aurora postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I have data for all the tables stored in CSV format in a S3 bucket. I wouldn't be able to use AWS Datapipeline. Is there a way to programmatically import this data into aurora postgresql db?

Comment: This seems like it has all the answers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html